# Unable to create Hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I am learning Perl Script from [here](http://www.perl.com/pub/2000/10/begperl1.html).
I am having problem creating Hash. The code is here:

```
print "Hello World!\n";
@days = ("1", "2");
print "There are $#days days\n";
print "1 is $days[0]\n";
%months = ("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3);
print "There are $#months keys\n";
print "a is $months[0]\n";
for $i (keys %months)
{ print "$i has value $months[$i].\n"}
```

Now its working fine with the array.
But for Hash its printing "There are -1 keys".
Also its not printing anything for the variable values in last to print calls.

Comment: Please [use newer version of the tutorial which is mentioned in the beginning](http://www.perl.com/pub/2008/04/23/a-beginners-introduction-to-perl-510.html) - the one you've mentioned is from 2000 and not [modern](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) at all!

Comment: @Xaerxess I find the older one better to understand! :)

Comment: @Cool_Coder: *Please* don't use that version of the tutorial: it is nearly thirteen years out of date! It was written before the availability of Perl 5 version 8, which was a landmark release that changed a lot about the way people used Perl. Version 10 and version 14 were also significant updates. We are now on version 16, and the release of version 18 is imminent! If you carry on learning version 6 you will learn a *lot* of bad habits that are no longer relevant, and it won't help you to understand modern Perl code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the array syntax on a hash, which does not do what you think at all. Instead of operating on your hash, you are operating on an array called `@months`. For example:

```
print "There are $#months keys\n";
```

This will look for the array `@months`, see that it is empty, and happily print `-1`.

When you do

```
for $i (keys %months) { 
    print "$i has value $months[$i].\n"
}
```

Perl will try to convert the keys `a`, `b` and `c` to numbers, which will be `0`. This will issue a warning:

```
Argument "a" isn't numeric in array element ...
```

Then it will print the empty array element `$month[0]`. Which will issue an undefined value warning. You do not get these warnings, because you did not use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

In your script. `strict` would have told you that `@months` has not been declared, and stopped this bug right away.

The syntax you should have used is:

```
print "There are " . (keys %months) . " keys\n";
...
print "$i has value $months{$i}\n";
```

Comment: Then how do I know how many keys are there in the Hash without converting the elements of Hash into an array & then finding the size of array?

Comment: @Cool_Coder Sorry, I got a phone call while I was editing the question to add that. It's added now.

Comment: Thanks for that additional info :)

Answer (score 3):

In Perl, accessing elements in a hash use a slightly different syntax to arrays. Use curlies for hashes, square brackets for arrays:

```
print "a is $months{a}\n";  # "a is 1"
```

And `$#months` is another way of saying 'last index of @months', when what you really meant was to count the number of keys in `%months`:

```
printf "There are %d keys\n", scalar keys %months;
```

If you insist on `print` instead of `printf`:

```
print "There are $#{[keys %months]} keys\n";
```

<sub>(but maybe it's a few steps ahead of where you want to be at the moment)</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I wanted to know whether the syntax mentioned by you is fast if the hash has large size?

Comment: I suggest you try it. If it isn't "fast enough" for your needs, come back with another question (though I doubt this would be a concern).

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'large', but this is the canonical way to find the number of keys in a hash, and I've never noticed it take any time at all. There's probably a shortcut in the implementation of `keys` to just count the key entries when it's evaluated in scalar context, so it won't actually be building an array of keys like it would in list context.

Comment: @TLP : Been fiddling around with your idea, and there doesn't seem to be any pattern that could be (ab)used: `$ perl -wle "for (grep {!($_%2)} 1..2E2) { my %m = (1..$_); print $_/2, ':'.%m; }'`

Comment: @Zaid Aha, that's what I was thinking might be the case. Guess I should have tested it out a bit. I should delete my comment.

Comment: @TLP : I'd just let it be... may be useful to someone in the future

Comment: @Zaid - For a hash with a million (or more) keys, you are creating an array with a million (or more) entries and then throwing it away in that third example. Better to use : `print "Num keys: @{[scalar keys %hash]}"`

Answer (score 0):

`$#months` and `$months[0]`refer to an array and not a hash. You access the value of a hash by using curly braces `$months{key}`.

Also, you should `use strict;` and initialize variables with `my()`. If you had done that, you would have gotten a compiler error that `@months` does not exist.